# How to handle incompatible portal types during merge using code?

Tags: apex, ajax, merge

I m doing merging using MergeRequest at Visualforce side,

```
for(var i=0;i < records.length;i++){
    if(i==masterRecordIndex){
        continue;
    }else{
        var mergeRequest=new sforce.MergeRequest();
        mergeRequest.masterRecord=objMaster;  
        mergeRequest.recordToMergeIds=records[i].Id;
        mergeRequests.push(mergeRequest);                   
    }
}           
var callback={
    onSuccess:onSuccess,
    onFailure:onFailure
};

sforce.connection.merge(mergeRequests,callback);
```

It works fine except for certain account it will gave this error

> The accounts cannot be merged. Selected records do not have compatible
>   portal types and cannot be merged together.

I read the solution [How do I merge Accounts that each have Partner and Customer Portal Users associated?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205350&language=en_US)  but I don't know how to implement this using code.Do I need update some fields,if yes what field?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to merge 2 active portal accounts of different type together. 
I gonna try to translate what Salesforce is proposing. I don't think doing this by Javascript will be the easiest, but here is the idea.

So you have 2 different Accounts:

**Acct1** - Partner Portal

**Acct2** - Customer Portal

1. The first thing to do is to create a temporary account(**Acct3**) with basic/required fields.

   ```
   Account Acct3 = new Account();
   //default basic fields
   insert Acct3;
   ```
2. Reparent all the contacts from both account(Acct1 and Acct2) to Acct3.

   ```
   List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Acct1.Id OR AccountId = :Acct2.Id];
   for(Contact cont : contacts) cont.AccountId = Acct3.Id;
   update contacts;
   ```
3. Disable Acct2 as a customer portal account

   ```
   Acct2.IsCustomerPortal = false;  //for Partner Account, user IsPartner
   update Acct2;
   ```
4. Now you need to make the merge. Your Acct1 should still be enabled. I think you know how to do that.
5. Reparent all contacts from Acct3 to Acct1(from step 2)

   ```
   for(Contact cont : contacts) cont.AccountId = Acct1.Id;
   update contacts;
   ```

I never try myself, but I think it should work. Now I'm not sure if you actually need step 1 and create a temporary account(**Acct3**), or could you just reparent directly all the contact from **Acct2** to the partner account (**Acct1**). I'm interested to see the output if you could let us know. Good Luck!